# Custom Flex Ant build task

Tags: apache-flex, ant, custom-build-step

A beginner's question.

I'm building a .swf with Flex Ant.

To my .swf I link a file, `target.as`, which I generate from file `source.txt` with command

```
./tool.sh source.txt > target.as
```

How can I add what is described in the above sentence to my ant build process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The exec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) executes any external program:

```
<exec executable="${basedir}/tool.sh" dir="${basedir}" output="target.as">
    <arg path="source.txt"/>
</exec>
```

So if you use the mxmlc ant task to compile your swf, you can define your build task like this:

```
<target name="build">
     <exec executable="${basedir}/tool.sh" dir="${basedir}" output="target.as">
          <arg path="source.txt"/>
     </exec>

     <mxmlc ....>
         ...
     </mxmlc>
</target>
```

Answer (score 2):

To run that command in Ant use the [`exec`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task.

```
<exec executable="tool.sh" dir="toolshdir" output="target.as">
    <arg value="source.txt" />
</exec>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/anttasks_1.html

You may also want to use the Flex "mxmlc" task instead of calling it with exec.  You can do a lot of configuration right within the XML if you'd prefer not to have to maintain the shell script.